# NGINX closes the upstream connection in 60 seconds

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using Nginx proxy server as a reverse proxy and https load balancer. Client connects to backend server through the reverse proxy in a load balanced environment. I have setup the correct https configuration (with ssl certificates and all) so that my ssl communication is going through proxy. In my case, server gracefully disconnect connection after 120 seconds (IDLE TIMEOUT of my server). But before that, nginx proxy itself closes after 60 seconds. This happens for every connect cycle. Due to which my client don't get ssl disconnect event and just receives tcp socket close event. If I change the IDLE_TIMEOUT of my server less than 60 seconds, everything works fine.
Want to know if there is any timeout on nginx server that I need to configure to keep the connection open for more than 60 seconds.

Ajay

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, copying it here.

Set values of proxy_read_timeout and client_body_timeout to timeout you want.

Comment: Insanely helpful question, and answer.  Upvoted for sure.